# Linux kernel which version changed the function parameters

Tags: git, kernel

I am build a out of tree module that has to work across range of kernel version. There has few internal API changes which require me use a #define to support those changes. I want to quickly locate which exact kernel version made those changes. How do I use git to browse through the history of a particular file/function changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
git log -S 'function_name' -- path/to/header.h
```

This will list only commits that modified the function `function_name`. It's likely that the last commit is the one that interest you, so get its SHA1 hash from the log output.

Then you want the first version to include this change, simply run

```
git tag --contains <sha1_hash>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `git blame` on the file.